# How can I debug & fix my crashing winforms app?

Tags: winforms, exception, frameworks

My winforms based application (developed on VS 2005) getting crashed after some time.The event viewer shows exception Event ID `1023`

> NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.1433-
>   Fatal Execution Engine Error

and `1000`

> Faulting application xxx.exe, version
>   2.1.3.6, stamp 4ddbbe56, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version
>   2.0.50727.1433, stamp 471ef729, debug? 0, fault address 0x00018265c.

I tried to reinstall dotnet framework 2.0 with sp2 but with no luck.

Followed article to fix this issue but issue remains.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384

Application is working on the system with admin rights.

Comment: Does your setup fit the profile described in that KB article? Specifically, does the user account your app is running under have a user profile?

Comment: This is the closest KB article for exceptions i found for event ID 1023 and 1000. Also admin rights is sufficient to run application.Is there any other setting needs to be done?

Comment: *Of course* admin rights are sufficient to run the app. :) But this KB article is specifically talking about the scenario where you're running under a user account with no profile

Comment: Kindly, suggest right KB article for same issue.

Comment: I'm not aware of one for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

A FEEE is thrown when the CLR notices that its internal state is corrupted.  That is almost always the garbage collected heap, destroyed by unmanaged code.  It can be very hard to diagnose.  Early versions of the CLR had some bugs that could cause it too but they have been all flushed out.  Try to isolate the problem by looking for bad pinvoke declarations or mis-behaving COM components used in your program.